# Redmine 500 Internal Server Error on My account page

Tags: ubuntu, log-files, ubuntu-14.04, redmine

I used [this](http://martin-denizet.com/install-redmine-2-5-x-git-subversion-ubuntu-14-04-apache2-rvm-passenger/) method to install redmine

I installed redmine in `/opt/redmine`, and i checked my log in `/opt/redmine/current/log/production.log`

I recently upgraded from 2.5.2.stable.13345 to 2.5.3.stable.14266

`My install info.
Environment:
  Redmine version                2.5.3.stable.14266
  Ruby version                   2.0.0-p481 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  3.2.19
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.8.8
  Git                            1.9.1
  Filesystem

Redmine plugins:
  redmine_agile                  1.3.2
  redmine_graphs                 0.1.0
  sidebar_hide                   0.0.7`

My tail of production.log

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 42.6ms

ActionView::Template::Error (cannot load such file -- tzinfo/definitions/Europe/London):
1: <%= labelled_fields_for :pref, @user.pref do |pref_fields| >
2: <p><= pref_fields.check_box :hide_mail ></p>
3: <p><= pref_fields.time_zone_select :time_zone, nil, :include_blank => true ></p>
4: <p><= pref_fields.select :comments_sorting,[[l(:label_chronological_order), 'asc'],[l(:label_reverse_chronological_order), 'desc']] ></p>
5: <p><= pref_fields.check_box :warn_on_leaving_unsaved ></p>
6: < end %>
lib/redmine/views/labelled_form_builder.rb:42:in `time_zone_select'
app/views/users/_preferences.html.erb:3:in `block in         app_views_users_preferences_html_erb__1218068006107140812_70264432515560'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1050:in `labelled_fields_for'
app/views/users/_preferences.html.erb:1:in     `_app_views_users__preferences_html_erb__1218068006107140812_70264432515560'
app/views/my/account.html.erb:43:in `block in     app_views_my_account_html_erb_373455605642633520_70264429441020'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1043:in `labelled_form_for'
app/views/my/account.html.erb:9:in       `_app_views_my_account_html_erb__373455605642633520_70264429441020'
```

Everything seems to be working except for "My account" page.

I have found this problem other places, but no solutions

[here](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/8960)

and [here](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/43672)

The file it's looking for doesn't exist, but I am lost as to the solution. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

After following the instructions below I have a new problem.

```
Web application could not be started

Cannot execute "/home/$USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/passenger-4.0.45/buildout/agents/SpawnPreparer": Permission denied (errno=13)

Application root
/opt/redmine/current
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and  PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
production
Ruby interpreter command

/home/$USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/wrappers/ruby

User and groups

Unknown

Environment variables

Unknown

Ulimits

Unknown
```

I have looked all over for a solution to this, and I've checked my permission and owners on every file/directory involved. Everything is owned by the same user, and I've moved everything to 777 and nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried checking to see if the gem is actually installed?

```
gem list
```

If it isn't installed, that's probably the problem.

If you are in the same directory as your Gemfile, then you should be able to just use:

```
bundle update
```

If that doesn't work, then you can manually install it.

Install information can be found [here](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo)

```
gem install tzinfo
gem install tzinfo-data
```

Then you may need to restart your application server.

Comment: I tried this, and commented in my answer under EDIT 1.

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer posted about installing tzinfo.  The second problem I had in the edit was my own fault.  

I installed tzinfo as root.  When I did that I broke a lot of things.  I had to uninstall tzinfo as well as any dependencies.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: `bundle update` fixed it for me. Thanks!